# Candlestick chart does not show with plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, spyder, candlestick-chart

Probably something really simple.

I use an example to plot a Candlestick chart using plotly, but the plot never show up!?

This is the code from https://plot.ly/python/candlestick-charts/

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],
                open=df['AAPL.Open'],
                high=df['AAPL.High'],
                low=df['AAPL.Low'],
                close=df['AAPL.Close'])])

fig.show()
```

I'm using last updated python and spyder4 on anaconda. I usually use matplotlib without problem.

Comment: Do you get any warning? What about the version of plotly?

Comment: no warning, nothing... Plotly is vs 4.5.3

Comment: Add `from plotly.offline import plot` at the top and `plot(fig)` instead of `fig.show()` at the bottom of your code. What happens?

Comment: Hooo it work great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an issue already considered in the [plotly community](https://community.plot.ly/t/plotly-in-spyder/5414/6):

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.offline import iplot
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],
                open=df['AAPL.Open'],
                high=df['AAPL.High'],
                low=df['AAPL.Low'],
                close=df['AAPL.Close'])])

iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Running this I get:
```NameError: name 'plot' is not defined```

Comment: Try `fig.show()` instead of `plot(fig)`. You can also try `iplot(fig)`, which is imported above. It seems `datetime` is not used here.